# Eclipse showing an error while open

Tags: java, 15.10, eclipse

I installed eclipse in my Ubuntu pc yesterday. Then when I tried to open it, there appeared an error like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have the Java installed by running

```
java -version
```

If it returns an error, run this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

Good luck !